Read .js file content in React component
I have a React component that displays and Iframe and I'm inserting into this Iframe <script> element:
const iframe = ref?.current;
const iframeWindow = iframe?.contentWindow;
const iframeDocument = iframeWindow?.document;

if (!iframeDocument) return;

const iframeHead = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const scriptElement = iframeDocument.createElement('script');

scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
scriptElement.innerText = ???; // Insert content of iframe.js here

iframeHead.appendChild(scriptElement);

I also have the .js file in the same component directory:
- iframe-wrapper
  - IframeWrapper.tsx
  - iframe.js // Import content from this file
  - index.ts

I dont want to have the js content stored and imported as const string. How can I get the content of iframe.js and set it as content of the <script> element?
